# Assigning value of a Vector3 to another Vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the following line of code, `_pro` is another class's instance that has a `Transform` called `Target` and `posi` is a `Vector3` as well and has a valid value.

```
_pro.Target.transform.position = new Vector3(posi.x, posi.y, posi.z);
```

I want to assign the value of `posi` to `Target.transform.position` but it throws a `NullReferenceException`.

After inspecting each part, `_pro` is `null`. Here is how I tried to instantiate _pro:

```
public projectile _pro;
GameObject go = GameObject.Find("enemy");    // go is not null
_pro = go.GetComponent<projectile>();        // _pro is null
```

Comment: Either `_pro`, `Target` or `transform` is null. Have a look in the debugger.

Comment: @cHRIS: _pro is null. I am editing the above code, please have a look and let me know why is _pro null. Thanks

Comment: I am facing problem in instantiating it properly, would be great if someone here could help me.

Comment: From the docs: `Returns the component with name type if the game object has one attached, null if it doesn't.`

Comment: I checked it and _pro is definitely null and is not assigned a value but I am unable to understand why is it so?

Comment: Well the null in this case means that the enemy game object doesn't have a projectile attached - so begin with figuring out why that is.

Comment: Where are you creating the projectile and attaching it to the "enemy"?

Answer (score 1):

The `"enemy"` game object that was found does not have a `projectile` component attached to it, so that is why `go.GetComponent<projectile>()` is giving you `null`.

You need to instantiate the projectile somewhere in your code.  You can do something like this:

```
go.AddComponent<projectile>(); // where go is the "enemy" game object
```

or this:

```
var pro = CreateInstance<projectile>();
pro.transform.parent = go.transform.parent; // go is the "enemy" game object
```